# Translation for a text that is not printed on the screen

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, multi-language

How can I enable the translation for a text that is not printed on the screen? I was recently implementing the translation to my plugin and everything worked as expected. But doing the tests I realized that I was missing something. There is a small piece of code in my plugin that creates terms based on a condition, but one of them is a text and I need it to be translated. how can I do? I understand that `__` and `_e` are just for static strings that are printed to screen.

```
if ( empty ( $cookie ) ) {
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, '- Default', 'directory' );
}
else {
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $cookie, 'directory' );
}
```

(- Default) is what I need to translate

Thanks to whoever can help me

Comment: can you be more specific about translation? Do you mean the localisation API built into WordPress for static strings? Or do you mean a plugin such as polylang or WPML for translating content from the database? `__` and `_e` are not meant to be used with dynamic values

Comment: I mean the wordpress API, the .mo and .po files. That's what I have implemented.

Comment: ok, the mo/po system is not intended for terms and other dynamic content, it's for static strings in PHP files, what you have in your question is dynamic data, nothing in your code block is appropriate for that system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a small piece of code in my plugin that creates terms based on a condition, but one of them is a text and I need it to be translated. how can I do? I understand that __ and _e are for the text that is printed on the screen.

*You don't, this is not something WordPress supports out of the box and you've misused the functions*, you should not be using `__` or `_e` for dynamic content that came from the database or the user.

`__` and `_e` are a part of the localisation API, intended for static strings in your theme and plugins such as labels.

For example:

```php
<p><?php echo __( 'Name', 'mytextdomain' ); ?>: <?php echo esc_html( $name ); ?></p>
```

In the above example, trying to pass `$name`, or a posts title/content into the `__` function would be extreme bad practice and a major mistake. Many would consider it a bug.

To translate content from the database such as tags, terms, posts, etc, you need to install a plugin.

As for where it works, `__` should work everywhere regardless of context.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself correctly. But I am not doing what you say, I am using __ and _e only for static strings. I understand from the beginning that they are not for anything else. Now I only need to translate that word (- Defautl) and I don't know how to do it, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: you don't, `- Default` is a reference to something in the database, it would be inappropriate to translate it using `__`, the same goes for any other function parameter

Comment: No no, it does not refer to anything, it is just a written text, the logic would be, if the string is empty, create the term with name (- Defautl). But it is just a text written by me, it does not refer to anything.

Comment: `- Default` would change depending on the users locale, resulting in that parameter changing so different terms would get used, it's dynamic data. Here `- Default` is not referring to output, it's referring to the name of something in the database, that's not what `__` is for. This API is intended for localising static strings on output, not translating strings on input

Comment: For example, if the user chose Spanish then it would localise to `- Defecto`, so that user would run this code and Defecto not Default would be passed to `wp_set_post_terms` and you would get a brand new term named `- Defecto` in the database, it would not set `- Default` as the term. If you want to translate Default for localisation you need a plugin to translate terms, even if it's a term you created

Comment: And that is exactly what I want, that for the Spanish user it is never (- Default) I want it to be (- Defecto) and so with all languages.

Comment: then I don't see what the blocker is, use `__(` around the string like you've done everywhere else. Remember, `_e(` is just a wrapper for `echo __(`

Comment: The initial problem is that I didn't know if the localisation API was going to work there since it's not a text that appears on the screen. in fact, I assumed it wasn't going to work. I didn't do any tests either. Now I'll do it, generate the translation files and see if it works.

Comment: that API works everywhere, it shouldn't be context dependent

Comment: Done, it works :).. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135580/discussion-between-chose-and-tom-j-nowell).